# How to make a python GUI application desktop size independent?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.4

I have created a GUI applcaition in python using Tkinter library. I have disabled resizing of the windows which appear. All the buttons and widgets which I have used are displaying correctly on the system on which i am developing. But when I run the application on other system, the size and location of the widgets became a mess.

Could you all please suggest how can I remove this issue and make the application system independent?

I have attached the code file. Please help here.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.4

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from UserWindow import UserWindow
import swiftclient as sc
import swiftclient.exceptions as swiftClientExceptions

class MyApp(Frame):
def __init__(self,parent):
    Frame.__init__(self,parent)
    self.parent=parent  
    self.images = []
    self.configureLoginWindow()
    self.createLoginWindow()

def configureLoginWindow(self):
    self.master.title("Music Library")
    self.master.resizable(False,False)
    w = 400   #Width of the Window
    h = 250   #Height of the Window
    # get screen width and height
    ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()#This value is the width of the screen
    hs = root.winfo_screenheight()#This is the height of the screen
    # calculate position x, y
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)

    #This is responsible for setting the dimensions of the screen and    where it is
    #placed
    self.master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

def createLoginWindow(self):
    #Create a 5*5 Grid
    self.grid()
    for columns in range (0,6):
        self.columnconfigure(columns, pad = 14,weight=1)
    for rows in range (0,6):
        self.rowconfigure(rows , pad = 14,weight=1)

    #Setting the image
    rawdata=Image.open('images/login.jpg')
    loginImage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(rawdata)
    self.images.append(loginImage)
    #Creating Label to store Image
    labelLoginImage = Label(image=loginImage,bg="white")
    labelLoginImage.grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=2,rowspan=5)
    #Creating Login Box
    labelUserName=Label(text="Username")
    labelPassword=Label(text="Password")
    labelWarning = Label(text="UserName OR Password is          wrong!!!!",fg='red')
    entryUserName=Entry(width=20)
    entryPassword=Entry(width=20,show="*")
           btnLogin=Button(text="Login",command=lambda:self.loginClickEvent(entryUserName.get(),entryPassword.get(),labelWarning))
    btnCancel=Button(text="Cancel",command=self.cancelClickEvent)

    labelUserName.grid(column=2,row=1,sticky=SW,pady=3)
    labelPassword.grid(column=2,row=2,sticky=NW,pady=3)
      entryUserName.grid(column=3,row=1,columnspan=2,padx=4,sticky=SW,pady=3)
    entryPassword.grid(column=3,row=2,columnspan=2, padx=4,sticky=NW,pady=3)
    btnLogin.grid(column=3,row=2,pady=3)
    btnCancel.grid(column=4,row=2,pady=3)
    labelWarning.grid_forget()

def loginClickEvent(self,usrName,password,labelWarning):
    try:
        #Validation with keystone client via swiftclient
        storage_url , token = sc.client.get_auth("http://172.18.9.100:5000/v2.0/",usrName,password,auth_version='2.0'
                                                 ,os_options=dict({"tenant_name": 'admin'}.items()))
        '''storage_url , token = sc.client.get_auth("http://192.168.0.7:5000/v2.0/",usrName,password,auth_version='2.0'
                                                 ,os_options=dict({"tenant_name": 'demo'}.items()))'''
        storage_url = storage_url[0:7] + "172.18.9.100:8080/" +      storage_url[23:]
        #Passing token and storgae Uri which we have received to User          Window page
        app=UserWindow(storage_url , token)

    except swiftClientExceptions.ClientException as unauth:
        labelWarning.grid(column=2,row=3,columnspan=3,sticky='N')
        print(unauth)

def cancelClickEvent(self):    
    self.master.destroy()


root=tk.Tk()
app = MyApp(root)
app.mainloop()
```

I dont have enough reputation to add the picture please help here.

By messy I means that the space between widgets is uneven and there size is also different.

Comment: What layout do you use? Did you hard-code the window size, or just disable resizing? Show some code.

Comment: Also, what exactly does `became a mess` mean? Do you maybe have some comparison images? Some more info about the two system setups might also be useful.

Comment: I have added the code and some more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have debugged the issue. Here are the thing that needs to be modified :-

1. While configuring rows and columns in grid. Use  Grid.columnconfigure and Grid.rowconfigure with weight as 1 or greater then 1.
2. The width property of widgets can vary with the kind of widget in use. In case of widgets having text values there width is specified in number of characters and if the widgets have images then there width is specified in pixels.

Now when I have moved my code from windows to Linux and ran that then the GUI is looking differently. The first reason is that I had earlier not used Grid methods as mentioned in point 1 Above.
Secondly, the font type and size play a vital role. If you don set the default font type and size explicitly then the GUI picks up the default font type of the system on which it is running.

I have given the same font size and font type manually on windows and linux then the buttons appear same.

I hope the answer is helpful. Here I am pasting the code after modification.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *   
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from UserWindow import UserWindow
import swiftclient as sc
import swiftclient.exceptions as swiftClientExceptions
import tkinter.font

class MyApp(Frame):
def __init__(self,parent):
    Frame.__init__(self,parent)
    self.parent=parent  
    self.images = []
    self.configureLoginWindow()
    self.createLoginWindow()

def configureLoginWindow(self):
    self.master.title("Music Library")
    self.master.resizable(False,False)
    w = 400   #Width of the Window
    h = 250   #Height of the Window
    # get screen width and height
    ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()#This value is the width of the screen
    hs = root.winfo_screenheight()#This is the height of the screen
    # calculate position x, y
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)

    #This is responsible for setting the dimensions of the screen and where it is
    #placed
    self.master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

def createLoginWindow(self):
    #Create a 5*5 Grid
    self.grid()
    for columns in range (0,6):
        Grid.columnconfigure(self.master,columns,weight=1)
    for rows in range (0,6):
        Grid.rowconfigure(self.master,rows , weight=1)

    #Setting the image
    rawdata=Image.open('../images/login.jpg')
    loginImage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(rawdata)
    self.images.append(loginImage)
    #Creating Label to store Image
    labelLoginImage = Label(image=loginImage,bg="white")
    labelLoginImage.grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=2,rowspan=5,sticky=NSEW)
    #Creating Login Box
    labelUserName=Label(text="Username" ,font=("Helvetica", 8))
    labelPassword=Label(text="Password",font=("Helvetica", 8))
    labelWarning = Label(text="UserName OR Password is wrong!!!!",fg='red',font=("Helvetica", 8))
    entryUserName=Entry(width=20,font=("Helvetica", 8))
    entryPassword=Entry(width=20,show="*",font=("Helvetica", 8))
    btnLogin=Button(text="Login",padx=1,font=("Helvetica", 8),command=lambda:self.loginClickEvent(entryUserName.get(),entryPassword.get(),labelWarning))
    btnCancel=Button(text="Cancel",padx=1,font=("Helvetica", 8),command=self.cancelClickEvent)

    labelUserName.grid(column=2,row=1,sticky=SW,pady=3)
    labelPassword.grid(column=2,row=2,sticky=NW,pady=3)
    entryUserName.grid(column=3,row=1,columnspan=2,padx=4,sticky=SW,pady=3)
    entryPassword.grid(column=3,row=2,columnspan=2, padx=4,sticky=NW,pady=3)
    btnLogin.grid(column=3,row=2,pady=10)
    btnCancel.grid(column=4,row=2,pady=10)
    labelWarning.grid_forget()

def loginClickEvent(self,usrName,password,labelWarning):
    try:
        #Validation with keystone client via swiftclient
        storage_url , token = sc.client.get_auth("http://172.18.9.100:5000/v2.0/",usrName,password,auth_version='2.0'
                                                 ,os_options=dict({"tenant_name": usrName}.items()))
        '''storage_url , token = sc.client.get_auth("http://192.168.0.7:5000/v2.0/",usrName,password,auth_version='2.0'
                                                 ,os_options=dict({"tenant_name": 'demo'}.items()))'''
        storage_url = storage_url[0:7] + "172.18.9.100:8080/" + storage_url[23:]
        #Passing token and storgae Uri which we have received to User Window page
        app=UserWindow(storage_url , token)

    except swiftClientExceptions.ClientException as unauth:
        labelWarning.grid(column=2,row=3,columnspan=3,sticky='N')
        print(unauth)

def cancelClickEvent(self):    
    self.master.destroy()


root=tk.Tk()
app = MyApp(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set the geometry:
`root.geometry("500x400+100+100")`

You must add it after initiating the Tk instance! The `500` in the above code signifies the **Width**, and the `400` here signifies the **height**, and the other 2 numbers signifies the position of the window on the screen!!